# How should I store battle effects?

Tags: c#, monogame

I have battle effects that can be anywhere from 50-150 frames (running at 60fps). I need to be able to draw each frame of the battle effect as an additive layer onto my game.

A frame could look something like these:

[image: Sample frame 1]

[image: Sample frame 2]

What is the best way to store these and render these for performance and memory considerations?

Here is a sample battle animation. Warning it is a 1920x2720 texture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRLtL.jpg

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Can you show us your initializing and drawing codes please?

Comment: @AhmentZambak My problem is that I have 150 individual frames that I'm not sure how to store. I will have 100s of these animations so I need to know how I can store them. I guess I'm trying to avoid having huge texture dimensions.

Comment: If you are creating the animations frame by frame I'm afraid you won't be able to compress it THAT much. The only thing you can do is to use a small image file format with good compression. However, if you can depict your animations with particles I'd suggest storing the raw data and generating the animations at runtime (Saves **A LOT** of disc space. You could even easily generate variations of the same effect). What is the size we are talking about now? How many different effects do you have, how large are they?

Comment: CREATE AN ATLAS

Comment: @LukeG Each animation as a .png could be 811KB. I've edited my post to show an example.